# Decompose (deconvolve) a 2-peaked pdf into 2 elementary pdfs

Tags: probability, matlab, mixture-distribution

How could I decompose a two-peaked (empirical) pdf into 2 say lognormals or other appropriate pdf in a straightforward way? I'd prefer in Matlab.

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like there's 3 or 4 components in that mixture.

Comment: Interesting, so how to approach the decomposition?

Comment: Just a guess. Wouldn't it be possible to do some sort of maximum-likelihood analysis using a product of two distributions you choose?

Comment: Are you able to state which (family of) component distributions you expect? If yes, then this means to fit a mixture model to the underlying data. The main way to do this is the [Expectation Maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Expectation_maximization_.28EM.29) which however is hardly straightforward. This is not an easy problem, at least not in generality. It is only a deconvolution problem if you start from the (estimated) densities and if the component distributions are exactly the same; and even then, deconvolution is quite tricky in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have log-normals you can easily fit a Gaussian mixture distribution object using the function [gmdistribution.fit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html). Notice that at some point the four-component fitting fails to converge and you get a warning about it. This is normal; not all random E-M initializations converge to a *good solution* within a set number of steps (100 here). Clearly smaller samples will converge less frequently while increasing the number of iterations the E-M algorithm is doing will increase the chances of the E-M converging.

After choosing the Gaussian mixture you think it is *the best* you can simply plot their corresponding PDFs for each component to get the plot you mention. Remember to multiply each PDF by the mixing proportion it has so you get some mixture that "vaguely" has area 1. :)

```
rng(1234,'twister') % Set the random seed for reproducibility
mus = [-1 9];       % means mu
sigmas = [3 4];     % variances sigmas
N = 2500;           % number of elements per component
M = 10;             % number of random restarts for E-M

% Generate some random numbers
y1 = random('normal', mus(1), sigmas(1), [N, 1]);
y2 = random('normal', mus(2), sigmas(2), [N, 1]);
y  = [y1; y2];

% Use gmdistribution.fit (or fitgmdist) to get fitted GMM
% specifying the number of components to investigate for as 
% well as the number of random initializations
GM_obj_1 = gmdistribution.fit(y,1,'Replicates',M);
GM_obj_2 = gmdistribution.fit(y,2,'Replicates',M);
GM_obj_3 = gmdistribution.fit(y,3,'Replicates',M);
GM_obj_4 = gmdistribution.fit(y,4,'Replicates',M);

% Get the best based on AIC (you could use the BIC or the
% loglikelihood to get something else (eg. AICc, etc.)
[best_AIC_score, assoc_num_comp] = ...
    min([ GM_obj_1.AIC  GM_obj_2.AIC GM_obj_3.AIC  GM_obj_4.AIC]);

% Plot the results
ksdensity(y); hold on
x = linspace(min(y)*2, max(y)*2, 1000);
plot(x ,GM_obj_2.PComponents(1) * pdf('normal', x, ... 
     GM_obj_2.mu(1), sqrt(GM_obj_2.Sigma(1))),'r')
plot(x ,GM_obj_2.PComponents(2) * pdf('normal', x, ... 
     GM_obj_2.mu(2), sqrt(GM_obj_2.Sigma(2))),'k')
legend('Original empirical density estimate', 'Comp. 1 PDF', 'Comp. 2 PDF');
grid on
```

[image: Quick-n-dirty KDE]

Comment: I am glad I could help! Good luck with the rest of the analysis!